# Validator (npm) Username Validation

Tags: node.js, validation, npm

I am building a web app with Node.js.

I am currently using the `validator` package to validate inputs. I would like to have only alphanumeric characters allowed, but with the period, underscore and hyphen allowed also. (. _ -)

Some sample code is below:

```
if (!validator.isEmpty(username)) {
    console.log('Username not provided');
} else if (!validator.isAlphanumeric(username)) {
    console.log('Username is not alphanumeric');
} else {
    console.log('Good Username!');
}
```

I would like to have somewhere in the code above that checks for periods, underscores, and hyphens and allows them to get through the `validator.isAlphanumeric` method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a regex for that.

```
if (!validator.matches(username, "^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]*$")) {
  console.log('Username not valid');
} else {
  console.log('Good Username!');
}
```

Explanation:

```
^ : start of string
[ : beginning of character group
a-z : any lowercase letter
A-Z : any uppercase letter
0-9 : any digit
_ : underscore
\.: Escaped character. Matches a dot
\-: Escaped character. Matches a  minus
] : end of character group
* : zero or more of the given characters
$ : end of string
```

You can check the correctness here: https://regexr.com/4r65m

Answer (score 0):

Slight refactor on the version from Gabriel Vasile.

```
if (!validator.isEmpty(username) {
    console.log('Username Empty');
} else if (!validator.matches(username, '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$')) {
    console.log('Username not Valid');
} else {
    consoe.log('Username Valid');
}
```

Thank you.